# Disable default evaluation for non-expressions in node REPL

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

According to [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl):

> The default evaluator supports direct evaluation of JavaScript expressions:

This can be a bit annoying (say for variable declarations, where `undefined` is returned):

```
> const m = 2
undefined // <--- disable when irrelevant ?
```

Can this feedback be disabled per command ? I tried adding a `;` at the end but that had no effect.